# Python: Writing to a specific position in a text file

Tags: python

I am writing co-ordinates to a text file, a sample data set looks as follows:

```
-11.700 8.827   9.247
-11.956 8.450   7.858
-12.511 9.655   7.129
-13.527 10.173  7.584
```

The co-ordinates are arranged x,y,z respectively.

I need the X co-ordinates to be written to the text file where the last digit in the number fall at character position 14, the last digit in Y co-ordinates falls at character position 27 and the last digit in the Z co-ordinates falls at position 40.

The only way I can think of doing it, is by taking the `len` of the number and filling the space accordingly, but this seem an "ugly" way of doing this. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the formatting operator `%` for this:

```
In [11]: x, y, z = -11.700, 8.827, 9.247

In [12]: '%14.3f %12.3f %12.3f' % (x, y, z)
Out[12]: '       -11.700        8.827        9.247'
```

Answer (score 1):

`string.rjust()` is what you want.

`line = ''.join([str(x).rjust(14), str(y).rjust(13), str(z).rjust(13)])`

Answer (score 0):

That's not ugly. Maybe you can make it more to your liking by introducing a helper function which takes the three numbers and returns the formatted string? You'll still need to add spacing and such, but at least it's separated from the rest of your code so it's not done inline.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: fout = open('output.txt', 'w')

In [3]: for line in open('input.txt', 'r'):
   ...:     x, y, z = [float(i) for i in line.split()]
   ...:     fout.write('%14.3f %12.3f %12.3f\n' % (x, y, z))
   ...:     
   ...:     

In [4]: fout.close()

In [5]: cat output.txt
       -11.700        8.827        9.247
       -11.956        8.450        7.858
       -12.511        9.655        7.129
       -13.527       10.173        7.584
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the formatting operator `%` suggested in other answers, I'd like to bring in the `str.format` method:

```
x, y, z = -11.700, 8.827, 9.247
"{:14.3f} {:12.3f} {:12.3f}".format(x, y, z)
```